# Give Windows 10 access to calendar but not gmail

Tags: windows, gmail, calendar

Is it possible to allow Windows 10 to sync the calendar with the Google Calendar while at the same time denying it access to email on GMail?  If yes, how?

Comment: What Calendar application are you planning to use.  It would have to support Google Calendar

Comment: Windows 10 calendar.